# textIsSelectable moves toolbar down

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I've added textIsSelectable attribute to some TextView's and trying to work with it... that's what I have

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After reading, you need to set the following in your theme:

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```